# Stuck at itunes build process

Tags: ios

I uploaded a build from Xcode but in iTunes, it was taking processing but not uploaded.

Anyone faced the same issue? I am stuck at processing!

[image: strong text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem once. I have tried everything, even created a new build and uploaded it again. The problem fixed itself after a while. My recommendation would be to wait for a while. Good luck!

Comment: Actually i am uploading since one week but it was same problem is there error in program?

Comment: No, it is not your fault. Apple service just stuck. Have you tried to upload a new build?

Comment: yes tried for 10 builds but it is visible in itunes in processing after 5 mins it will be gone.

Comment: In this case I see no other option than contacting Apple support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload using Application Loader.

Comment: I had tried application loader also but it was also same problem.